# Laravel Model Observer handle events outside Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5, observers

I am new to Laravel and working on a system.

Right now my system is divided into 2 parts, one of which is in core Php and other I am re-coding in Laravel. Now I want to trigger some action when some Db operation happens and as I understand that can be done using Laravel Model Observers.

But in my case, the event generator wouldn't be laravel, but the core php code and I want to handle the triggers in Laravel. Is this possible?

Any help and guidance on the same would be nice.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far.

Comment: why don't use database triggers in direct way

Comment: @MartinZabel as per Laravel Model Observer, I have successfully observed a table for insert and updates. But this insert and updates happens within Laravel framework. I need to observer events that happen outside the laravel framework and catch them in laravel framework.

Comment: @GoudaElalfy Can you please explain more in detail. Thanks